# Using Like Special Word to Compare Strings

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a VBA Macro that works perfectly fine except for one small piece. The Macro is supposed to allow the user to enter a string and then search a reference list and output any matches. I did this by looping through the possible options and having any matches put into a new element of an existing array. However, when I try to reference the input cell, I get a mismatch error even though the variable 'Criteria' is a string.

The following code works perfectly fine...

```
Dim StrName As Range,
Dim Criteria As String
Dim ArrOutput() As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim Rng As Range

Criteria = "Some String" ' is a string that the user wants to search for
x = 1
Set StrName = Sheets("Reference").Range("A2")
Set Rng = Sheets("Reference").Range("A2:A596")

'Loops through Rng checking if StrName contains Criteria
'Dumps any positive results into a new element of an array
For Each StrName In Rng
    If StrName Like "*" & Criteria & "*" Then
        ReDim ArrOutput(1 To x)
        ArrOutput(x) = StrName
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next StrName

'Should print array - will add functionality to allow array to be longer than one element
Range("B9") = ArrOutput
```

However, this code does not work

```
Dim StrName As Range
Dim Criteria As String
Dim ArrOutput() As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim Rng As Range


Criteria = Range("B7") ' is a string that the user wants to search for
x = 1
Set StrName = Sheets("Reference").Range("A2")
Set Rng = Sheets("Reference").Range("A2:A596")

'Loops through Rng checking if StrName contains Criteria
'Dumps any positive results into a new element of an array
For Each StrName In Rng
    If StrName Like "*" & Criteria & "*" Then
        ReDim ArrOutput(1 To x)
        ArrOutput(x) = StrName
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next StrName

'Should print array - will add functionality to allow array to be longer than one element
Range("B9") = ArrOutput
```

**The only difference being that I can declare the condition string directly, but when I try to reference the same string from an input cell the code breaks.**

This has been bugging me for a couple days now, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the value inside `B7` when you use this code? And what does `Debug.Print "*" & Criteria & "*"` actually give you? Are you sure the value is on the then active worksheet since `Range("B7")` has no explicit sheet reference but just the implicit active one. The same with `Range("B9") = ArrOutput`

Comment: Here `Criteria = Range("B7")` VBA does not know in which worksheet that range is and same here `Range("B9") = ArrOutput`. **Always** specify a worksheet for a range as you did here `Sheets("Reference").Range("A2")`.

Comment: Turns out the condition in B7 had a space at the end and the Like condition was reading the space within the asterisk causing the condition to not be met. Thanks so much for the quick help!

Comment: When reading user input it's often a good idea to use `Trim()` - eg - `Criteria = Trim(Range("B7").Value)` in case they entered some extra spaces.